# How does a program shut down when reading farther than memory allocated to an array?

Tags: arrays, crash, size, parameter-passing

Good evening everybody, I am learning C++ on Dev C++ 5.9.2, I am really novice at it. I intentionnally make my programs crash to get a better understanding of bugs. I've just learned that we can pass a char string to a function by initializing a pointer with the address of the array and that was the only way to do it. Therefore we should always pass to the function the size of that string to handle it properly. It also means that any procedure can run with a wrong size passed in the argument line hence I supposed we could read farther than the allocated memory assigned to the string.

But how far can we do it? I've tested several integers and apparently it works fine below 300 bytes but it doesn't for above 1000 (the program displays characters but end up to crash). So my questions are :

How far can we read or write on the string out of its memory range?
Is it called an overflow?

How does the program detect that the procedure is doing something unlegit?

Is it, the console or the code behind 'cout', that conditions the shutting down of the program?

What is the condition for the program to stop?

Does the limit depend on the console or the OS?

I hope my questions don't sound too trivial. Thank you for any answer. Good day.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void change(char str[])
{
    str[0] = 'C';
}

void display(char str[], int lim)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++) cout << str[i];
}

int main ()
{
    char mystr[] = "Hello.";
    change(mystr);
    display(mystr, 300);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The CPU is interrupting with a page-fault when you read from or write to memory you're not supposed to read/write.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior when you read past the end of an array is undefined.  The compiler is free to implement the read operation in whatever way works correctly when you don't read beyond the end of the buffer, and then if you do read too far - well, whatever happens is what happens.

So there are no definite answers to most of your questions.  The program could crash as soon as you read 1 byte too far, or you could get random data as you read several megabytes and never crash.  If you crash, it could be for any number of reasons - though it likely will have something to do with how memory is managed by the OS.

As an aside, the normal way to let a function know where a string ends is to end it with a null character rather than passing a separate length value.